# Output classes as plain text and include dots

Tags: jquery, attr

I'm trying to get classes from elements as text in span and inserting a dot in the class. I first tried replacing spaces with dots but that didn't work out. I really need to target the individual classes and add dots for each of them so I tried the each selector:

```
    <span class="   foo    bar    baz   "></span> 

var cl = $('span').attr('class');

    $(cl).each(
        function(){
           var text = '.';
            $(text).insertBefore(this);
        });

    $('span').text(cl);
```

Doesn't seem to work.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gPYnc/1/)

So the ouput would have to be:

```
.foo.bar.baz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't actually doing the `.each` as the value of `cl` is a string from the `$('span').attr('class');`

What you want to do is take the string and split it by space.

```
var cl = $('span').attr('class');

var classes = cl.split(' ');
var textList = "";
for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++)
{
    if (classes[i].length > 0)
    {
        textList += "."+classes[i];
    }
}

$('span').text(textList);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gPYnc/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the class name(s) as a string with plain JavaScript:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++){
    var classes = spans[i].className.split(/\s+(?=[a-z0-9])/i);
    spans[i].className = classes.join(".");
    alert(spans[i].className);
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/gPYnc/6/

Comment: That's why I put a comment, "your logic here"...I've shown you how to get the class names as a string and you can manipulate them as a string. However, I added a more detailed example.

Comment: This will also add a dot at the end

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple regex. For example:

```
// Get class string
var cl = $('#test').attr('class');

// Replace all whitespace blocks with a .
// and remove any trailing .
var output = cl.replace(/\s+/g, '.').replace(/\.+$/, '');

console.log(output); // e.g. ".foo.bar.baz"
```

[JSFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/9tNW6/)

Comment: @Youss I've added a simple fix for this - see code/jsfiddle added

Comment: Thank you very much +1 but I like Turnerj answer because I can "understand" it a bit more (not good with Javascript) :)